# How to add date range to this SQL in trac?

Tags: sql, trac

We have the following query working as expected and have one last thing left in our modification of trac:

```
SELECT
   p.value AS __color__,
   owner AS __group__,
   id AS ticket,
   severity,
   status,
   priority,
   summary,
   component, 
   milestone, 
   t.type AS type, 
   time AS created, 
   description AS _description, 
   reporter AS _reporter, 
   changetime AS modified, 
   time AS _time,
   reporter AS _reporter 
FROM 
   ticket t 
   LEFT JOIN enum p 
   ON p.name = t.priority 
      AND p.type = 'priority' 
WHERE 
   status = 'closed' 
ORDER BY 
   owner, 
   p.value, 
   t.type, 
   time
```

We need to date range to this to only pull out tickets closed between Aug 5 and Aug 17. We need to be able to edit the query to change the date range as needed as we need a few different date range. Can you please advise how to change the query to have date range between Aug 5 to Aug 17 ?

Comment: what dialect of sql are you using?  postreSQL, sqlLite, etc.

Comment: With Trac SQL dialect should not matter - just use generic expressions understood by *any* of the supported db backends. At least it is current Trac philosophy to emphasis compatibility by not relying on any proprietary statement, and it works well AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to choose `t.changetime` as a constraint? Any edit or comment after closing the ticket would mess with your report. Anyway, for now let's assume you can rule this out somehow.

As hinted in my comment to Austin's answer, I can't confirm nor did I ever expect that a date string would work here. `t.changetime` holds Integers (Trac 0.11) or INT/LONG values (Trac 0.12) so must be compared against such values.

I'll show you in short how to produce them here:

```
$> date -d '2011-08-06' +%s
1312581600
$> date -d '2011-08-18' +%s
1313618400
```

As you see the conversion from string to POSIX seconds after 1970-01-01 is quite easy on any terminal window running a shell like BASH. For Trac 0.12 you'll need microseconds format, so just add 6 zeros or use

```
echo $(($(date -d '2011-08-18' +%s) * 1000000))
1313618400000000
```

Note, to include full 2011-08-17 you'll want to go past it, to the beginning of the following day, hence '2011-08-18' might be what you want to convert.

Now put it all together and you'll get

```
AND t.changetime BETWEEN 1312581600 AND 1313618400
```

or for Trac >= 0.12

```
AND t.changetime BETWEEN 1312581600000000 AND 1313618400000000
```

Comment: Hasienda: 1 .Thanks, that works - though cygwin shell is giving me output of 13136508 instead of 13136184 - but I guess thats not a big issue. 2. Just wondering if there is a better field you recommend to track when a ticket was closed if not t.changetime ?

Comment: to 1.: I think, that this is corresponding to our different timezones. My system is currently at CEST +02:00, yours must be 8 hours ahead then, like i.e. Sydney, so will always produce an reverse-proportionally lower UTC value for the same date, because that date string is taken as local time but gets converted to UTC timestamp.

Comment: to 2.: Nothing, that is as straight-forward as *changetime*. I just put out the warning to make you aware of the potential weakness of the approach, depending on how strong your regulations are. A tamper-proof concept would involve writing a separate *closetime* on change to status 'closed'. If you like to investigate further, I'd recommend you to take a look at http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DynamicFieldsPlugin, that might be up to the job of conditionally setting (custom, hidden) ticket fields.

Comment: Thank you  - I cant vote your answer as I get error saying it needs atleast 15 reputation points and I am new here. However this public comment should let admin and others know that your answer is the one that resolved this.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the end of your WHERE clause:

> AND `changetime` BETWEEN '2011-08-05' AND '2011-08-17'

I'm assuming 'changetime' is the field that stores the date the ticket was closed.

Comment: Did you test? Changetime, or better t.changetime column has values of type INT/LONG and translating string dates is not business of any SQL transaction engines I know. According to my tests this **fails miserably** - as expected. Only chance to make this work is, if there was a custom field changetime with close dates stored as strings. But this wasn't mentioned nor hinted by anything in sams SQL statement. Furthermore this would need a list of exact date strings for the full date range, like AND tc.changetime IN ('2011-08-05','2011-08-05','2011-08-06',...,'2011-08-17') - not quite practical.